# PostgreSQL: How to SUM attributes including a JSONB field, and retain table shape?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I am working with Postgres 9.4. I have a table with a JSONB field:

```
     Column      │         Type         │                             Modifiers
─────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 id              │ integer              │ not null default
 practice_id     │ character varying(6) │ not null
 date            │ date                 │ not null
 pct_id          │ character varying(3) │
 astro_pu_items  │ double precision     │ not null
 astro_pu_cost   │ double precision     │ not null
 star_pu         │ jsonb                │
```

I want to retrieve the summed values by date of various attributes, including anything in the JSONB array (which it is safe to assume has depth 1), and return the values in the same structure as in the original table.

This is the query I'm using right now:

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(total_list_size) AS total_list_size,
       json_object_agg(key, val)
FROM (
    SELECT date,
           SUM(total_list_size) AS total_list_size,
           key, SUM(value::numeric) val
    FROM frontend_practicelist p, jsonb_each_text(star_pu)
    GROUP BY date, key
    ) p
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

It does not fail, and the JSON is presented as a dictionary which is how I want it. However, the summed value of `total_list_size` looks hugely too large. I think it must be being summed twice.

How can I get the correct summed value for `total_list_size`, while retaining the same shape results?

Comment: Update: If I substitute `AVG` for `SUM` in the outer query, I get the right results, although I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `jsonb_each_text()` in the subquery causes the column `total_list_size` is replicated as many times as number of items in `star_pu`, so `avg()` shows a proper result.

To get one `total_list_size` for a `date` you can use a parallel subquery that accumulates the value independently.

```
select *
from (
    select date, json_object_agg(key, val) total_star_pu
    from (
        select date, key, sum(value::numeric) val
        from frontend_practicelist, jsonb_each_text(star_pu)
        group by date, key
        ) s
    group by date
    ) s
    join (
        select date, sum(total_list_size) total_list_size
        from frontend_practicelist
        group by date
        ) t
    using(date)
order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [Postgres extension](https://github.com/furstenheim/jsonb_deep_sum) to sum jsons. Once you have it installed you can simply do:

```
select date, sum(total_size_list), jsonb_deep_sum(star_pu) from frontend_practicelist;
```